# Haskell Type Error From Function Application to Function Composition

Tags: function, haskell, types, function-composition, pointfree

This question is related to this [Function Composition VS Function Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3116165/function-composition-vs-function-application) which answered by antal s-z.

How you can get this ?

```
map has type (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
head has type [a] -> a
map head  has type [[a]] -> [a]
```

Why the following code has type error for function composition ?

```
 test :: [Char] -> Bool
 test xs = not . null xs

 getMiddleInitials :: [String] -> [Char]
 getMiddleInitials middleNames = map head . filter (\mn -> not . null mn) middleNames
```

but this does not have type error

```
getFirstElements :: [[a]] -> [a]
getFirstElements = map head . filter (not . null)
```

Is it a must to write a point free function in order to utilize the function composition ? 
I still not very understand the usage of function composition.

Please help. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your error here is actually really simple.  If you remember the last part of [my answer to your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3116165/function-composition-vs-function-application/3116798#3116798), the `.` operator has higher precedence than anything *except* for function application.  Thus, consider your example of

```
test :: [Char] -> Bool
test xs = not . null xs
```

This is parsed as `test xs = not . (null xs)`.  Of course, `null xs` has type `Bool`, and you can't compose a boolean, and so you get a type error.  Thus, you could make your examples work like so:

```
test :: [Char] -> Bool
test xs = (not . null) xs

getMiddleInitials :: [String] -> [Char]
getMiddleInitials middleNames =
  (map head . filter (\mn -> (not . null) mn)) middleNames
```

Of course, writing it this way is unusual, but it would work fine.

And no, there are other uses of function composition besides point-free style.  One example is to use function composition for some things (*e.g.* the argument to `map` or `filter`), but specify the rest.  For instance, take this contrived example:

```
rejectMapping :: (a -> Bool) -> (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
rejectMapping p f = map f . filter (not . p)
```

This is partly point-free (`not . p`, for instance, and we left off the final argument), but partly point-full (the existence of `p` and `f`).

Comment: Not really understand the last part which rejectMapping example.

Comment: Which part of it don't you understand?  The motivation behind it, what it's supposed to do, or how it works?  It only uses things you've already seen, so if you think about it, you should be able to follow it!

Answer (score 4):

That's just because function application `x y` has higher precedence than composition `x . y`

```
 test :: [Char] -> Bool
 test xs = (not . null) xs
 -- #      ^          ^

 getMiddleInitials :: [String] -> [Char]
 getMiddleInitials middleNames = (map head . filter (\mn -> (not . null) mn)) middleNames
 -- #                            ^                          ^          ^    ^
```